# How to change the style of TokenizingTextBox from Windows Community Toolkit?

Tags: uwp, windows-community-toolkit

I'm using the TokenizingTextBox control from the Windows Community Toolkit in my UWP app, but I can't seem to find a way to change its default style. I've searched the documentation and the internet, but I haven't found any clear instructions on how to do this.

I want to change the appearance of the control, including the font size, color, and padding. Can anyone provide a step-by-step guide or sample code on how to achieve this?

I've tried setting the style in the XAML file by using the Style property, but it doesn't seem to work. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are properties called `TokenItemStyle`,`SuggestedItemContainerStyle`, `AutoSuggestBoxTextBoxStyle` and `AutoSuggestBoxStyle` according to the document:[TokenizingTextBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/tokenizingtextbox). You might need to change there styles by yourself. You could also check the source code here: https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/tree/rel/7.1.0/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.SampleApp/SamplePages/TokenizingTextBox

Comment: For questions about commmunity toolkit, I'd suggest you ask in github: [ToolKit issues](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues)